# Select query less of doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm tring to get the result of a query where the number id is < of 21 this one is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT users.name, users.surname, users.username, inbox_msg.message, inbox_msg.id_msg, inbox_msg.occured_at, image_upload.name_image
FROM inbox_msg
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = inbox_msg.id_user
INNER JOIN image_upload ON image_upload.id_image = users.profile_image
WHERE inbox_msg.id_conversation = 1
AND inbox_msg.id_msg < 21
LIMIT 10
)mex
ORDER BY occured_at ASC
```

I don't know why the result obtained are the first 10 result of my table. I attach the picture of my wrong results.

[image]
it should be give me id_msg: 20,19,18,17,16 ecc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `LIMIT 10` is applied without the ordering. You should re-arrange your query to apply the ordering before the limit, so that the rows with the highest `id_msg`s would appear in the top ten:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT users.name, users.surname, users.username, inbox_msg.message, inbox_msg.id_msg, inbox_msg.occured_at, image_upload.name_image
    FROM inbox_msg
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = inbox_msg.id_user
    INNER JOIN image_upload ON image_upload.id_image = users.profile_image
    WHERE inbox_msg.id_conversation = 1
    AND inbox_msg.id_msg < 21
    ORDER BY id_msg DESC -- <<== Add this line
    LIMIT 10
)mex
ORDER BY occured_at ASC
```